# Google Speech to Text domain adaptation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to do domain adaptation with text data to improve the speech to text results of Google Cloud Speech-to-Text.
I have already done this with the Azure and AWS Speech to text systems. There you just throw a huge text corpus with domain specific language at the system and you usually get better results after that.

For the Google speech to text system I have not found anything like that. What I found is this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation
This sadly only allows very specific adaptations (manually adding words that should be recognized better).
I have tried doing a keyword extraction on my text corpus and putting the extracted words in the `speech_contexts[{"phrases": []}]` parameter but this didn't change my results.

Is there any way to train the Google speech to text service (language model) with a large text corpus for domain adaptation?

Comment: It is not possible to use Google's speech-to-text API model to be retrained using the users input data. You mentioned that you did try adding `speech_contexts` but it did not work. You can adjust the [value of boost](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#SpeechContext) from 0 to 20 and see if it will improve the use of `speech_contexts`. Other than that, you can either use [models](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enhanced-models) phone call or video to further enhance the results of your transcription.

Comment: On my end, the video model has performed best. (Haven't tried the phone model, though)

Comment: There are model adaptation 
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/projects.locations.customClasses/patch?authuser=1

You can create custom class tokens and phrase sets.